# Get a shortestPath from neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

i have a task to make a program that finds a shortest way between 2 towns. I had to make it, by using C# and neo4j. The problem is the returning type of neo4j query i tried with two queries and the problem was same I can't find what kind of a data structure i have to use to recieve objects .

**Neo4j query:**

```
MATCH  p=(a:City{name:"Pleven"})-[*]->(b:City{name:"Mezdra"})
RETURN p AS shortestPath, 
       reduce(km=0, r in relationships(p) | km+r.km) AS totalDistance
       ORDER BY totalDistance ASC
       LIMIT 1
```

**C# query 1:**

```
CypherQuery query1 = new CypherQuery("MATCH  p=(a:City{name:'"+from+"'})-[*]->(b:City{name:'"+to+"'}) RETURN p AS shortestPath, reduce(km = 0, r in relationships(p) | km + r.km) AS totalDistance ORDER BY totalDistance ASC LIMIT 1", new Dictionary<string,object>(), CypherResultMode.Set);
            var paths = ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<List<string>>(query1);
```

**C# query 2:**

```
var query1 = client.Cypher
                .Match("p=(a:City{name:{from}})-[*]->(b:City{name:{to}})")
                .WithParam("from",from)
                .WithParam("to",to)
                .Return((p) => new PathsResult<City>{
                    nodes = Return.As<IEnumerable<Node<City>>>("p AS shortestPath,reduce(km = 0, r in relationships(p) | km + r.km)"),})
                .Limit(1);
var result = query1.Results;
```

**C# recieved pack :**

```
{"columns"frown emoticon"shortestPath","nodes"],"data":[[{"directions"frown emoticon"->","->","->"],"start":"http://localhost:7474/db/data}
```

Comment: This post: http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2013/07/23/neo4jclient-ndash-getting-path-results.aspx might give you some help - not got lots of time right now to really look into... and would need example data etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just use the "shortestPath" built-in function in Cypher.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-finding-paths.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok i come to kind of a solution i found a way to Return the distance between towns, the problem now is that, when i wrote p=Return.As("shortestPath")
it has been translated as RETURN shortestPath AS p.
Current version of code:

```
 var query = client.Cypher
                       .Match("p=(a:City{name:{from}})-[*]->(b:City{name:{to}})")
                       .WithParam("from", from)
                       .WithParam("to", to)
                       .Return((p,order) => new
                       {
                           shortestPath = Return.As<City>("p"),
                           order= Return.As<int>("reduce(km = 0, r in relationships(p) | km + r.km)")


                       }).OrderBy("order ASC")
                       .Limit(1);
```

If any suggestions please help

Comment: To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context. If you still need help with this question, please edit your question to clarify it instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's full solution if somebody needs:

```
 var query = client.Cypher
                       .Match("p=(a:City{name:{from}})-[*]->(b:City{name:{to}})")
                       .WithParam("from", from)
                       .WithParam("to", to)
                       .Return((p,order) => new
                       {
                           shortestPath = Return.As<IEnumerable<Node<City>>>("nodes(p)"),
                           order= Return.As<int>("reduce(km = 0, r in relationships(p) | km + r.km)")


                       }).OrderBy("order ASC")
                       .Limit(1);

            var result = query.Results;

            foreach (var res in result) {
                foreach (var city in res.shortestPath.ToList()) {
                    Console.WriteLine(city.Data.name);
                };

            }
```